# Ubuntu 20.04 never starts install

Tags: system-installation

I have a Gateway FX6850 tower with an EVGA Geoforce GTX 1070. It has run Win7 well for years.
I stuck a USB drive in it and booted Ubuntu 20.04 fine, but I did not allow it to install over Windows.
I installed an SSD with the plan of installing Ubuntu there and dual booting to Windows of the old hard drive, Ubuntu off the new drive.
Now when I stick the USB drive in the system and boot, it usually gives me a few options, one of which is install Ubuntu. I select that. The screen goes blank (backlight still on) and never does anything. Sometimes it goes CHIME! on the monitor speakers after a while. I have waited 30 minutes after that and nothing ever happens.
I tried booting windows off the hard drive (still works fine) and formatted the SSD (A 2TB from Crucial). Windows was able to initialize and format the drive with no problems. I booted off the USB drive again, same behavior. Screen goes blank and never recovers.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  Did the validation of the write to your installed media complete successfully?  (if it didn't, I'd not trust it to install). If you can't validate that media on that machine, you could try it on another box, but if it fails there too (to either successfully validate or provides any issue/warning/error-message), I'd assume the write to your install media was invalid & return to prior step.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem is with your installation media. the common problem is the creating the usb media. so my answer 8s never use Rufus for creating a bootable USB for linux. instead use something like etcher. because i had many problems with Rufus before. you can try etcher in the link below.

https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: Yeah, I used Rufus. But the media worked fine on the system before I installed the SSD, and when I put the system back in the original configuration the media worked again. I installed the SSD on a different sata plug and the media worked  to completion. How can the USB media be at fault when swapping sata cables fixes it?

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive was sata disk0, I move it to sata1 so I could put the SSD on as disk 0. Win7 boots off the hard drive as disk0 or 1. Win7 let me format an mount the SSD as sata drive0. I tried removing the hard drive, did not help. I tried moving the SSD to SATA drive1, now Ubunti is proceeding to install as expected, no blank screens, asking for keyboard etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there might be problem with your bootable usb stick, not with HDD or SSD.

Either it has an **error with 20.04ubuntu ISO image** or cause an **error during making bootable usb** otherwise all things should be good as per you described.

Try,making bootable USB again.

***here are some helpful way for making bootable usb without any error***.

- Fresh download the 20.04 ubuntu image using official site - [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

> (it requires minimum of 8GB of USB stick for making 20.04 ubuntu
> bootable usb)

- format partition of your usb stick and make bootable device.
- `using windows`- you can use [rufus](http://rufus.ie/) app for making bootable usb.
- `using linux`- you can use **startup disk creator** to make bootable usb.

now ,after that your usb is ready for installation.
try it.

Comment: Seems there is a major problem with xunbuntu 20.04.  Keep getting "Not a typewriter" error on multiple machines.  xunbuntu's 16.04 and 18.04 never had this problem.  Using DVD with iso.  sha256sum (checksum) comes out good.